# SharePoint User removal procedures and policies

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-accounts

What are your policies and procedures for removal of users?

I'm looking to hear from the community to what some best practices are. In particular, I'm looking to see if anything else is done after the removal of a user from AD and the example policies around that.

Examples:

- Remove user profile from site collections
- Use PowerShell script to remove any orphaned accounts
- Third party software?

Answer (score 1):

Personally it has never been something I've done, only until recently because it was a billing cost as determined by our hosting partner. Weekly we have ControlPoint going through our farm purging the disabled users from the site.

In all other previous places of employment, user cleanup wasn't a big priority because the AD accounts were disabled, and SCA access was limited to a few select people. We left it up to site owners to manage their permissions and remove employees who left if they wished.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric... I have inherited a large Farm that has been without an Administrator for sometime with no governance policies or Site Admins. So, I'm looking for ideas and some Best Practices user administration

Comment: I consider it to only be an issue if you aren't using AD (forms based auth) or there's a billing component necessary to clean up the users.

Comment: At my workplace, AD accounts are likewise disabled after a departure, but there is also a policy that anyone responsible for access management is expected to remove those users from their own systems as well. It seems moot to me given that it's impossible for the user to get in the network in the first place, but I suppose there are potential performance gains by purging unused permissions.

Comment: I guess I'm looking at it as cleanup... I have roughly 10,000 dead/orphaned users accounts, which ends up being real mess when going through Site Collections and trying to manage users and groups

Comment: @DanHenderson yes there is that expectation in most places, but how often do those notices get to people in positions that administer SharePoint spaces? The expectation is that people would remove users, the reality is they don't for the most part.

Comment: @EricAlexander Indeed. I believe at my company, it's the departing employee's manager that is responsible for notifying appropriate admins. And I don't suppose there's any practical way for that manager to identify SharePoint Groups that the user was in directly (i.e. not through AD groups). As a SCA, my only trigger would be attempting to send an email to someone and getting the pre-bounce warning from Outlook.